# Create a non numerical column based on < or >= numerical value of another column in R

Tags: r

I have a df$column

```
df$column (-0.5, 1, -0.5, 0.78, -0.78, 0, -1)
```

and I would like to create a new column with values of "<med" or ">=med" based on values in column2

```
df$column (-0.5, 1, -0.5, 0.78, -0.78, 0, -1)
df$new    (<med, >=med, <med, >=med, <med, <med)
```

my current code which I get the error of problem with "mutate()' input ... input is if else(..)

```
df2 <- df %>% mutate(new = ifelse(df$column >=0 ~ ">=med", ifelse(df$column <0 ~ "<med")))
```

any assist is always appreciated

Comment: what is 'med' the median?  or 0?

Comment: It is median. So I don't actually know if ifelse with >=0 and <0 is the correct way to code for this. I would like to delineate values based on the median.

Comment: df2 <- df %>% mutate(new = factor(column >=0, labels = c("<med", ">=med")))

Comment: If you like to delineate based on the median, then you definitely shouldn't use ```<0``` but rather ```<median(df$column)```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would this do the job?:

```
df$column (-0.3678, 1, -0.67, 0.78, 0.78, 0, -1)
df$column2 <- NA
med <- median(df$column)
df$column2[df$column < med] <- "<med"
df$column2[df$column >= med] <- ">=med"
```

Or in a more efficient way using `ifelse`:

```
df$column (-0.3678, 1, -0.67, 0.78, 0.78, 0, -1)
df$column2 <- ifelse(df$column < median(df$column), "<med", ">=med")
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, if I understand you correctly, but wouldn't that work?

```
df$new = ifelse(df$column >= 0, ">=med", "<med")
```

If you want dplyr solution try:

```
df_new <- df %>%
mutate(new = if_else(column >= 0, '>=med', '<med'))
```